Python: Dragging a source widget onto a target widget to change its colour
I am looking at Python drag and drop within Tkinter. I am doing this as a proof of concept for something which I am working on. However, it doesn't quite work as expected. I create two Buttons (one red and one blue), and the idea is that when I drag and drop either of the buttons, over the other, the colour should change to cyan. This however isn't working. My code is here:
from tkinter import *

# import tkinterdnd2 as tkd

widget_x_restore = 0
widget_y_restore = 0


def drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    global widget_x_restore
    global widget_y_restore

    widget_x_restore = widget.winfo_x()
    widget_y_restore = widget.winfo_y()
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y
    widget.lift()


def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)


def restore_position(event):
    widget = event.widget
    print(widget)
    widget.place(x=widget_x_restore, y=widget_y_restore)


def drop(event):
    target_button = event.widget  # Access the target button
    if isinstance(target_button, Button):
        target_button.config(bg="cyan", fg="cyan")  # Change target button color


root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400+200+100")

button1 = Button(root, text="button1", bg="red", fg="red", width=10, height=5)
button1.place(x=10, y=100)

button2 = Button(root, text="button2", bg="blue", fg="blue", width=10, height=5)
button2.place(x=200, y=200)

button1.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
button1.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
button1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", restore_position)
button1.bind('<<Drop>>', drop)

button2.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
button2.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
button2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", restore_position)
button2.bind('<<Drop>>', drop)

root.mainloop()

There is no colour change. So the first question is, what am I doing wrong?
UPDATE: Having changed the drop() function to:
def drop(event):
    target_button = event.widget  # Access the target button
    print(f'>>>> {target_button}')
    if isinstance(target_button, Button):
        target_button.config(bg="cyan", fg="cyan")  # Change target button color

It appears that the callback is not being executed? I get zero output from the print statement.
The second question is, is it possible to detect the source widget, from the "drop" bind? Ultimately I want to be able to grab the colour of the source button, and use it to set the colour of the target button.
UPDATE2:
Thanks to the help and comments from @furas and @acw1668, I have produced this class. I'll leave it here in case it's useful for someone else, going through the same learning curve:
    import tkinter as tk
    
    class DnD():
        """Drag and Drop management class, used to drag one widget over another, target widget. 
        The target widget then takes on the colours of the dragged
        widget."""
        payload = ['', '']
    
        def __init__(self, widget, enable_drag=True, enable_drop=True):
            self.widget = widget
            root.update_idletasks()
    
            self.widget_x_restore = widget.winfo_x()
            self.widget_y_restore = widget.winfo_y()
    
            if enable_drag:
                self.widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.drag_start)
                self.widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.drag_motion)
                self.widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.restore_position)
                DnD.payload = [self.widget.cget('background'), self.widget.cget('foreground')]
    
            if enable_drop:
                self.widget.bind("<<Drop>>", self.drop)
    
        def drag_start(self, event):
            """The drag_start method is a callback function bound to a mouse action (Button-1 click)."""
            widget = event.widget
            widget.startX = event.x
            widget.startY = event.y
            widget.lift()
    
        def drag_motion(self, event):
            """Callback method, used in binding to mouse pointer motion, causing the dragged widget motion."""
            widget = event.widget
    
            x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
            y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
            widget.place(x=x, y=y)
    
        def drop(self, event):
            """Register a widget as a drop target."""
            target_button = event.widget  # Access the target button
            fg_colour, bg_colour = DnD.payload
            target_button.config(bg=bg_colour, fg=fg_colour)  # Change target button color
    
        def restore_position(self, event):
    
            self.widget.place(x=self.widget_x_restore, y=self.widget_y_restore)
            root.update_idletasks()  # move top widget (source widget), to access widget below (target widget)
    
            x, y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
            target = event.widget.winfo_containing(x, y)
    
            target.event_generate("<<Drop>>")
    
    
    # --- main ---
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    root.geometry("600x400+200+100")
    
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text="button1", bg="red", fg="red", width=10, height=5)
    button1.place(x=10, y=100)
    
    button2 = tk.Button(root, text="button2", bg="blue", fg="blue", width=10, height=5)
    button2.place(x=200, y=200)
    

    # Register the buttons for drag and drop.
    button1_dnd = DnD(button1)
    button2_dnd = DnD(button2)
    
    root.mainloop()

I use a class variable to regiister the colours of the dragged button, and when the "<<Drop>>" event is detected by a "drop registered" button, the colours get retrieved from the variable.

What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that your if statement is evaluating to True to allow the call to target_button.config to succeed? Have you verified that target_button is what you think it is?

Hi Bryan. I just re-checked and it appears that the drop() callback function doesn't appear to be being called at all.  Apologies for the confusion,.

python - How can I create a Drag and Drop interface? - Stack Overflow

example in source code cpython/Lib/tkinter/dnd.py at main · python/cpython

probably to use <<Drop>> you may need external module tkinterdnd2. And it may need to use dnd_bind() instead of bind() and TkinterDnD.Tk() instead of Tk()

but it seems TkinterDnD is for droping external files or external text, not for droping widgets.

you should run it in restore_position() but it will gives only dragged button. To get target widget you may need to run root.update() (to move source button to previous place) and use .winfo_pointerxy() and winfo_containing(x,y) from python - How can I create a Drag and Drop interface? - Stack Overflow

furas, I did look at tkinterdnd2, but struggled to find any decent documentation, and the examples they provide, all appear to have external data sources.

You can use tkinterdnd2 on tkinter widgets, but you cannot have the visual effect of dragging the widget around.

acw1668, so how is a visual effect achieved with tkinterdnd2?

The visual effect is shown on the mouse cursor.

for standard tkinter.dnd you can see source code tkinter/dnd.py and there is example which you can run with python -m tkinter.dnd. For module tkniterdnd2 you can see source code [tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py]https://github.com/Eliav2/tkinterdnd2/blob/master/tkinterdnd2/TkinterDnD.py) but it doesn't have example. Besides I see DND_FILES, DND_TEXT which suggest that it is for dragging files or parts of text from external programs to tkinter - so it may not have method to drag widgets.

I found folder demos in tkinterdnd2

I think '<<Drop>>' exists only when you use module tkinterdnd2.
But it seems this <<Drop>> works only for external files and external text, not for widgets.

You should do it in restore_position - similar to code in answer
python - How can I create a Drag and Drop interface? - Stack Overflow
Problem is that it gives top widget under mouse - so it needs update() to move source widget to old place and then target widget is top widget under mouse.
def restore_position(event):
    widget = event.widget
    print('source:', widget)

    widget.place(x=widget_x_restore, y=widget_y_restore)
    root.update_idletasks()  # move top widget (source widget), to access widget below (target widget)
    
    x,y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
    target = event.widget.winfo_containing(x,y)
    print('target:', target)
    
    if isinstance(target, tk.Button):
        target.config(bg="cyan", fg="cyan")  # Change target button color


Full working code:
import tkinter as tk


def drag_start(event):
    global widget_x_restore
    global widget_y_restore

    widget = event.widget

    widget_x_restore = widget.winfo_x()
    widget_y_restore = widget.winfo_y()
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y
    widget.lift()
    
def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget

    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)


def restore_position(event):
    widget = event.widget
    print('source:', widget)
    
    widget.place(x=widget_x_restore, y=widget_y_restore)
    root.update_idletasks()  # move top widget (source widget), to access widget below (target widget)
    
    x,y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy()
    target = event.widget.winfo_containing(x,y)
    print('target:', target)
    
    if isinstance(target, tk.Button):
        target.config(bg="cyan", fg="cyan")  # Change target button color

# --- main ---

widget_x_restore = 0
widget_y_restore = 0

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("600x400+200+100")

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="button1", bg="red", fg="red", width=10, height=5)
button1.place(x=10, y=100)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="button2", bg="blue", fg="blue", width=10, height=5)
button2.place(x=200, y=200)

button1.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
button1.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
button1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", restore_position)

button2.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
button2.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
button2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", restore_position)

root.mainloop()


I think it is better to call target.event_generate("<<Drop>>") instead of checking whether target is a button and calling .config() at the end of restore_position().

@acw1668 good point - target should change its config. Maybe later I will try to add it to full code.

Is there a way of detrmining the widget object that is being targeted by the drop?

in answer I use x,y = event.widget.winfo_pointerxy() target = event.widget.winfo_containing(x,y) but this needs to move source to access widget behind source. Other idea: get list of all widgets and check x,y with every widget -something like this you can see in example in tkinter.dnd - but this check only parent widgets but in your code widgets are not child-parent but rather sibling

BTW: if you would use canvas (with create_window() to put widgets on canvas) then it has functions to get all objects in some area - and it doesn't need to move source - ie canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)

see also canvas.find_overlapping() canvas.find_below() 8.6. Methods on Canvas widgets
